# How to use functions defined in other .c files in ulib.c on xv6 operating system?

Tags: c, operating-system, xv6

I'm working on a ticket lock on xv6 operating system. Here is my code

```
void
lock_init(struct lock_t* lk) {
  lk->ticket = 0;
  lk->turn = 0;
}

extern void pushcli(void);
extern void popcli(void);

void
lock_acquire(struct lock_t* lk) {
  pushcli();
  uint myturn = xchg(&lk->ticket, lk->ticket + 1);
  while (lk->turn != myturn)
    ;
  __sync_synchronize();
}

void
lock_release(struct lock_t* lk) {
  __sync_synchronize();
  xchg(&lk->turn, lk->turn + 1);
  popcli();
}
```

However, when I entered `make qemu`, an error occurred:

```
gcc -fno-pic -static -fno-builtin -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -Wall -MD -ggdb -m32 -Werror -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie   -c -o ulib.o ulib.c
ld -m    elf_i386 -N -e main -Ttext 0 -o _cat cat.o ulib.o usys.o printf.o umalloc.o
ld: ulib.o: in function `lock_acquire':
/home/kamichanw/os-lab/Xv6-Syscall/src/ulib.c:120: undefined reference to `pushcli'
ld: ulib.o: in function `lock_release':
/home/kamichanw/os-lab/Xv6-Syscall/src/ulib.c:131: undefined reference to `popcli'
```

`pushcli` and `popcli` are functions defined in `spinlock.c`.
Here is xv6 source code: [xv6 source code](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public)

I guess the problem is in `Makefile`, but I have no clue on fixing it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't declaring `pushcli` and `popcli` in `spinlock.h` and including it?

Comment: @MichaelM. I have tried to declare pushcli and popcli in spinlock.h, which doesn't help at all.